# Critical difference plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, statistics, statistical-test

I need help regarding generating the critical difference (CD) plot of my groups using python

```
import Orange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
names = ["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", 
         "M13" ]
 avranks =  [11.85, 7.10, 10.30, 6.75, 7.15, 7.10, 10.85, 7.0, 7.55, 4.85, 5.20, 3.60, 
            1.70 ]
 cd = Orange.evaluation.compute_CD(avranks, n=10, alpha='0.05', test="nemenyi")
 Orange.evaluation.graph_ranks(avranks, names, cd=cd, width=15, textspace=1.5, 
 reverse=True)

 plt.show()
 print('CD value:', cd)
```

The code above generated the CD plot using nemenyi test. However, whenever, I want to generate the CD plot using Bonferroni-Dunn Test, I got an error on the 5th line (cd= ...) that says "list index out of range". My code is found below:

```
import Orange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
names = ["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", 
         "M13" ]
 avranks =  [11.85, 7.10, 10.30, 6.75, 7.15, 7.10, 10.85, 7.0, 7.55, 4.85, 5.20, 3.60, 
            1.70 ]
  cd = Orange.evaluation.compute_CD(avranks, n=10, alpha="0.05", test="bonferroni-dunn")  
  Orange.evaluation.graph_ranks(avranks, names, cd=cd, width=10, textspace=1.5, 
  cdmethod=0, reverse=True)

  plt.show()
  print('CD value:', cd)
```

Please I will be glad if anyone can help provide information on how to solve this problem. Also, I am searching for the ***statistical Table of critical values for the two-tailed Bonferroni-Dunn Test***. Can anyone provide a line to download this statistical table?

Thanks